# how to separate the numbers and text in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

How could i separate the numbers that are on the left side of the text in excel?

[image: Example]

Comment: If using VBA, use the `Val` function (which will take everything prior to the first non-numeric character and return the value of the numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of your texts start with an uppercase, then with a formula you could do it like this:

```
=MID(A2,MIN(FIND({"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"},A2&"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")),LEN(A2))
```

Comment: It probably comes from the ";" that are in your computer ","
I edited my answer, does it work now?